# Dealing with 0's in loglog regression by using indicator functions I(x > 0)?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, logarithm, feature-scaling, indicator-function

Assume we want to estimate the following model

$y = e^{\beta_0} * x_1^{\beta_1} * x_2{\beta_3}$ which we can linearize into
$\log(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 * \log x_1 + \beta_2 * \log x_2$

Assume that the IV's can have zero value entries.

To deal with this why does one not just insert indicator variables as:

$\log(y) = \beta_0 + I(x_1 > 0)\beta_1 * \log x_1 + I(x_2 > 0)\beta_2 * \log x_2$ where as $I(x > 0) = 1$ if $x > 0$ else $0$.

I have not seen anyone do this and i wonder why is that?

Comment: zero observations of X contribute nothing to the regression because any value of coefficients produces zero output, i.e. exact match to left hand side. thus, you can simply remove the zero values from the training data set. keeping zeros only props up regression diagnostics without actually helping with accuracy of the estimation

Comment: we still have the intercept?  just removing them might not be possible since it may remove a large portion of the dataset, lets say we have alot of ($x1=0, x_2 >0$) and ($x_1 > 0, x_2=0$) datapoints.

Comment: If you look at your model, which is the first expression, you will see @Aksakal 's point - a zero for either $x_1$ or $x_2$ makes the output zero regardless of the values of the coefficients, so the observation contributes nothing to the estimation procedure.  Consequently, dropping the observation(s) is the right thing to do.

Comment: @jbowman but what about the second model which is the one we actually fit?

Comment: As you have realized, you can't fit it if you include the observations with zeroes.   Note that your proposed fix *changes* the model to a different one.  Considering the answer below, think about $x_1 = 0.0001$ and $\beta_1 = 1$.  If $x_1$ moves to zero, i.e., decreases by 0.0001, you effectively replace it with 1, which rescales the right-hand side by a factor of about 10,000 relative to $x_1 = 0.0001$.   This is a huge asymmetry relative to the effect of increasing $x_1$ by 0.0001.

Comment: You might find it insightful and constructive to think about how $\log y$ can differ from the modeled expression.  For example, maybe $\log y$ is a measurement that varies randomly above and below the model; or maybe $y$ has been rounded; or whatever.  That perhaps is the most important consideration for resolving your problem, because it leads to very different solutions.

Comment: another thing you didn't touch on is the errors: are they multiplicative? if they're additive then the log transformation itself would be problematic. consider $y=x^\beta+\varepsilon$ - how would you log transform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion is equivalent to using the function `if x<=0 then 0 else log (x)`. This has a big discontinuity at 0, since the log of a small number is a large negative number.

If most values of X are large, and none are negative, then the usual workaround is log(x+1).

Comment: edited it, meant $log(y) = \beta_0 + I(x_1 > 0)\beta_1 * x_1 + I(x_2 > 0)\beta_2 * x_2$ ... thus the intercept remains.. is it still an issue?

Comment: My comment still applies. The prediction for $x1=1/1000000$ will still be very different from the prediction for $x1=0$